# On globally generated vector bundles over a smooth projective surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

If $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf on a projective space $\mathbb P^n$ such that it is $m$-regular i.e. $H^i(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal F(m-i))=0$ for all $i>0$, then there exists a proposition in the literature (sometimes attributed to Castelnuovo) which states that $\mathcal F(k)$ is generated by its global section if $k \geq m$.

This can be considered as a sufficient criterion for global generation of a coherent sheaf on a projective space.

In this context, my question is that does there  exist in the literature a sufficient criterion  for global generation for vector bundles on a smooth projective variety $X \subset \mathbb P^n$?

I'm more interested in the case of vector bundles over surfaces (e.g. rank $2$ bundles (not necessarily ample)  over $K3$ surfaces and surfaces of general type in $\mathbb P^3$)

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Since your surface can be embedded in a projective space your vector bundle is a coherent sheaf on the projective space and you can apply Castelnuovo. So, are you asking for something else?

Comment: @Mohan, Do you mean if $j: X \to \mathbb P^n$ is the embedding, then one can use $H^i(\mathbb P^n, j_{*}(\mathcal F(m-i))) =H^i(X, \mathcal F(m-i)) $ to show that $ j_{*}(\mathcal F)(k)$ is globally generated on $\mathbb P^n$ for $k \geq m$ (and from there global generation of $\mathcal F(k)$ over $X$)?

Comment: I meant exactly that.

Comment: @Mohan, just to make sure that I understand the details correctly, we can write $H^i(\mathbb P^n, j_{*}(\mathcal F(m-i))) =H^i(X, \mathcal F(m-i))$, because $X, \mathbb P^n$ are Noetherian and separated and the closed immersion is always affine and also finite. Then the condition $H^i(X, \mathcal F(m-i))=0$ for $i >0$ gives us $j_{*}(\mathcal F)(k)$ is gg on $\mathbb P^n$ for $k \geq m$. Let $m=0$, then this means the map $H^0(\mathbb P^n, j_{*}(\mathcal F)) \to j_{*}\mathcal F_{p}$ is surjective for all $p \in \mathbb P^n$. For $x \in X$, taking $p=j(x)$ we get that $\mathcal F$ is gg on $X$.

Comment: @Mohan, So here the sufficient condition for $\mathcal F$ to be gg on $X$ is that $H^i(X, \mathcal F(m-i))=0$ for all $i >0$ and for $m=0$ (Please correct me if this is wrong).

Comment: Yes, the cohomology is exactly the same because a finite Cech cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$ by open affines induces one of $X$, and this gives an isomorphism of chain complexes by the definition of the pushforward. Also you may need that $j$ is an affine map so the pushforward on coherent sheaves is an exact functor.

Comment: Also perhaps the projection formula to show that the pushforward plays nicely with the short exact sequence computing local sections: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344126/the-projection-formula-for-quasicoherent-sheaves